# how to get JSON value from HTTP response?

Tags: java, json, http, get

I would like to retrieve the value of a JSON file from an HTTP request. Unfortunately, I do not know how to proceed.
I am using the GET method:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(new URI("http://localhost:3333/command/core/get-csrf-token"));
HttpEntity entity = client.execute(get).getEntity();
```

I do get the expected file as I tried:

```
return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

and get as output: `{"token":"myToken"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert JSON string into `JSONObject`( from org.json) and then get then token using `getString()` method

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
String token = result.getString("token");
```

Reference: http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject-java.lang.String-

Comment: whats the maven package for this?  springframeworkboot.configurationprocessor? json.internal.json_simple? Please add to answer, thanks !

Comment: @mattsmith5 from `org.json.JSONObject` and also updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
String token = jsonObject.getString("token");
```

Comment: whats the maven package for this?  springframeworkboot.configurationprocessor? json.internal.json_simple? Please add to answer, thanks !

Comment: No need to add any maven package, `org.json` is part of `java.lang.Object` .

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use regex(don't need additional libs).

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String json = "{\"token\":\"myToken\"}";

    System.out.println(extractToken(json));

}

public static String extractToken(String json){

    String regexToken = "(?:.*\\\"token\\\"\\s*:\\s*\\\")(?<token>.*?)(?:\\\".*)";
        
    Pattern patternToken = Pattern.compile(regexToken, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcherToken = patternToken.matcher(json);
    
    if(matcherToken.matches()){
        return matcherToken.group("token");
    }else{
        return "token_not_found";
    }

}
```

This will work even on a json with multiple fields. The only condition is to be only one `token` field in the entire json.